# Keeping track of items added to a page on button click

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a for loop inside a button for an image gallery. When you click the button it will get the next group of items and add them to the page until there are no items left to grab. I was originally keeping track of the position in the array by adding the amount of items that should be added with each click to the previous value on each click. I wanted to change these *vars* to *const*, but if *const* in ES6 is not supposed to change (stay constant) how do you achieve this same result by not changing the value of the variables? Are my methods of keeping track of the current count of items not how I should be doing this?

```
var itemCurrent = 10; // Starting number of items on page.
var itemsAdded = 15; // Number of items to add to page per button click.

document.getElementById('myButton').addEventListener('click', function() {

  for (let i = itemCurrent; i < itemCurrent + itemsAdded; i++) {
    if(i < data.projects.length) {
      //Do Stuff---------------------
    }
  }
  itemCurrent = itemCurrent + itemsAdded;
                
});
```

Comment: If you variable is `changing` how can it be a `const` ?

Comment: @NisanthReddy That is why I am asking if I should be doing this another way. From what I understand var should not be used in ES6 and the only way I can think of doing this is by using a variable.

Comment: if you can't use `var`, try it with `let` but pay attention to the scope differences between var and let

Comment: Just use [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)

Answer (score 0):

I thought maybe there would be a more elegant way to do what I wanted, but it seems using *let* instead of *var* and leaving everything the way it was is the best way.

Comment: There seems to be an idea out there that `let` is somewhat evil. It's not. Good practice is simply: create all your variables as `const`. If at some point one has to be reassigned, then switch it to `let`. That's all there is to it

Comment: That will just save you some mistakes where you would inadvertently change the value of a variable that is not supposed to change. Also it might help the interpreter optimize your code but nothing is less certain